# Oil, brake, servicing reminder lights turn off using OBD-II

Tags: obd-ii, abs, service, supplemental-restraint-system, scan-tool

I am doing a project to reset oil, brake, servicing reminder lights etc. using OBD-II Bluetooth scanners (VGate and [OBDLink SX Scan Tool](https://www.scantool.net/scan-tools/pc-based/obdlink-sx-scan-tool/)). Basically, trying to do what enhanced OBD-II scanners are capable of doing (e.g. [Launch Tool](http://www.x431store.com/)) with these scanners.

But, I am unable to find out the mechanism in which these enhanced OBD-II scanners do these tasks (like resetting service reminder intervals, removing service reminder lights, reading ABS, BCM, Airbag faults etc.). Is it even possible to do the above mentioned tasks using the VGate and Scan Tool scanners? Are there any particular modes and/or PID for this?

The cars used for my project testing are: Mahindra Scorpio (diesel) 2015 model and Hyundai i10 Era (petrol) 2012 model.

Comment: I believe this is off topic here.

Comment: i don't think you're going to find the info for free your best best would be to pay into the oem service sites or capture communications between a scantool and whatever computer/pid you want to access.